# Getting the value of a specific field in flutter firebase realtime database

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the value of a specific user from the firebase realtime database but when I try to do so the value is always null.
But when I print the whole object it works fine.

```
void getType(String email) {
final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
ref
    .child('users')
    .orderByChild('Email')
    .equalTo(email)
    .once()
    .then((DatabaseEvent snap) {
  if (snap.snapshot.value != null) {
    Map<dynamic, dynamic>? data =
        snap.snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>?;
    String? userType = data?["userType"] as String?;
    print('User type: $userType');

    print('Data : ${snap.snapshot.value}');
  } else {
    print('No data found for email: $email');
  }
});


}
```

This is the output of `print('Data : ${snap.snapshot.value}');`:

> Data : {-NTVZFFxx1fi4Aj4X_nZ: {Email: yy@tt.com, PhoneNumber: 4, ID: 66768, userType: Office, Name: ss}}.

You can see that it works fine, on the other hand the output of the "print('User type: $userType');" is:
(User type: null)

[image: The database]

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your code doesn't take that list into consideration. To do this, you should loop over the results in the [`snapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot-class.html) that you get:

```
.then((DatabaseEvent event) {
  DataSnapshot snapshot = event.snapshot;
  if (snapshot.exists) {
    snapshot.forEach((child) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> data = child.value! as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
      String? userType = data["userType"] as String?;
      print('User type: $userType');
    })
  } else {
    print('No data found for email: $email');
  }
})
```